# data not written in CSV stored in s3

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using Python boto3 to create and upload a csv file as follows

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    with open('/tmp/test.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
        fieldnames = ['emp_name', 'dept', 'birth_month']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerow({'emp_name': 'John Smith', 'dept': 'Accounting', 'birth_month': 'November'})
        writer.writerow({'emp_name': 'Erica Meyers', 'dept': 'IT', 'birth_month': 'March'})
        response = s3.upload_file('/tmp/test.csv', 'my-bucket', 'test.csv')
```

This creates a file `test.csv` in the S3 bucket but its empty. There are no errors, any idea?

Comment: Can you try with `response = s3.upload_file('/tmp/test.csv', 'my-bucket', 'test.csv')` outside of the `with` block. Maybe the content of the file hasn't been yet flushed to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to use [smart-open](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/1.3.3/) instead of s3.upload_file. It will help you with simple files operations.

In your case you can easily do:

```
from smart_open import open
import boto3

s3_session = boto3.Session()

with open('s3://my-bucket/my-folder/my_file_name.csv', 'w', 
          transport_params={'session': s3_session}) as fout:
    fout.write('my,row,1\n')
    fout.write('my,row,2\n')
```

It also support some compression format, simply specifing the extension desidered (.gz for example), you'll not think about compression/encoding ecc